# Delphi OAuth authentication

Tags: delphi, oauth, twitter-oauth, delphi-xe3

I made an application that works with the twitter API to generate tweets.
Now I want to expand my application but to do the things I want in my application I have to authenticate with the twitter API.

The best example I found was [here](http://chuckbeasley.com/index.php/2009/05/22/using-oauth-for-delphi-with-twitter/)
But I can't seem to figure out how I can authenticate.

Is there anyone that has experience with this or if there is a good reliable OAuth class for delphi? 
I dont consider the class in the example from the link as reliable since this post is from 2009. If you can prove me wrong, please do :)

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Paragraphs 1, 2, 3 and 5 are superfluous. I suggest you remove them and leave the 4th alone.

Comment: http://oauthdelphi.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/oauthdelphi/OAuth.pas?revision=2&view=markup

Comment: @opc0de Nice find, but I cannot find any explanation on how to actually use it...

Answer (score 0):

I have made that same search myself a few months ago and come up empty handed. A similar question recently arose on the [ADUG](http://www.adug.org.au/) mailing list, and again to no avail.

I don't believe  that there is a publicly available Delphi library for OAuth and/or Open Id. IMHO, this is an open source project ripe for development by some-one with the time and motivation.

Comment: Well there must be some way to do it, or a workaround... I just get the feeling there is something I'm missing.

Comment: I am not saying you can't roll your own solution. I am just saying there isn't an out-of-the-box solution via a publicly available library. Your question asks for a class - which is more or less the same as asking for a solution via a someone's published library.